# Facebook login popup not working on chrome on tablets

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I have a Facebook application on a Website that opens the standard login popup via the javascript sdk (FB.login()). The code is really simple and standard:

```
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            window.tryInit = window.setInterval(function() {
                if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
                    console.log('FB loaded');
                    window.clearInterval(window.tryInit);
                    FB.init({
                        appId: ...,
                        channelUrl: ...,
                        status: true,
                        cookie: true,
                        xfbml: true
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('FB not loaded yet');
                }
            }, 100);
        }

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('a#login').click(function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    alert("OK");
                });
            });
        });
```

When i try to use the login function on an iPad 2 with the Chrome browser, it opens a new tab that tries to connect to a Facebook url (m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth...), but this results to a blank page, perhaps after some kind of error happening. The same link works correctly form the same tablet with the Safari browser, and on desktops and smartphones.

Has anyone else ever experienced the same issue? Any suggestion?

Thank you guys!

EDIT: the same issue is happening on an iphone4 with Chrome, but not with Safari.

Comment: Those popups don't usually work on mobile web

Comment: I mean popup or a new tab. Actually, the problem i described was that chrome opened a new tab that never managed to connect to facebook; safari, instead, opened a new tab and successfully connected. The same thing happend on chrome over the iphone 4.

Comment: are you logged in via browser on the ipad?

Comment: @Scorpion no, i don't, while from the iphone i'm logged to Facebook by default.

Comment: Having this same problem as well

Comment: @user2658889 unfortunately i never managed to make the fb popup work in those cases..instead i chose to show a simple redirect link when the page is viewed from mobile, and kept the popup only for desktop users.